# Split column base on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Split a column into different columns base on the tables below

```
Phone type
    ptype_id|description
    1      HOME
    2      WORK
    3      CELL

Phone 
phoID|pho_PhoneNum|ptype_id
1        012313       1
2        0132465      2
3        1324654      3
....
```

base on the above tables the output should display cell,home,work in its own column
Such as

```
 phoID|Home|Work|Cell
   1   null|null|124
   2   null|156 |null
   3   789 |null|null
```

any advice or direction will be appreciated thank you

what I have tried to isolate the work type. but it returns null as work 
but there are values in phoID

```
   Select  pho.phoId, 
    (Select pho2.pho_phoneNum from Phone pho2 
     join PhoneType pht2 
     on pho2.ptypeid=pht2.ptypeid  
      And pht2.description='Work'
      And pht2.ptypeid=2 
     Where pho2.ptypeid=pho.ptypeid  
      And pho.ptypeid=2) as Work
     from Phone pho;
```

Comment: Is it the count or something else you are displaying in desired output. Desired output is ambiguous. Do you need to sum the number of phones with same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregation and join two tables

```
select phoID, max(case when ptype_id = 1 then pho_PhoneNum end) as Home,
       max(case when ptype_id = 2 then pho_PhoneNum  end) as Work,
      max( case when ptype_id = 3 then pho_PhoneNum  end) as Cell
     from phone p join phoneType pt
    on p.ptype_id=pt.ptype_id
    group by phoID
```

Comment: Bear in mind this will fall down if it is possible to have multiple phone numbers due to slowly changing updates etc, in which case ordering will be required.

Answer (score 1):

```
select phoID,
       case when ptype_id = 1 then pho_PhoneNum else NULL end as Home,
       case when ptype_id = 2 then pho_PhoneNum else NULL end as Work,
       case when ptype_id = 3 then pho_PhoneNum else NULL end as Cell
from phone
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample Data

```
CREATE table #Phonetype
( ptype_id INT,
 description VARCHAR(20)
 )
 INSERT INTO   #Phonetype
 SELECT 1,'HOME' UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'WORK' UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,'CELL' 

CREATE table #Phone 
(phoID INT,
pho_PhoneNum BIGINT,
ptype_id INT)

INSERT INTO #Phone
SELECT 1,012313 ,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,0132465,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1324654,3
```

Using PIVOT in Sql server

```
DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(max),
        @IsnullColumns nvarchar(max),
        @Sql  nvarchar(max)


SELECT @Columns= STUFF((SELECT ', '+QUOTENAME([description]) FROM  #Phonetype t
INNER JOIN  #Phone  p
On t.ptype_id=p.ptype_id FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')


SET @Sql='
SELECT [phoID], '+@Columns+'
FROM
    (   SELECT T.ptype_id, 
            [description],
            phoID,
            pho_PhoneNum
        FROM #Phonetype t
        INNER JOIN  #Phone  p
        On t.ptype_id=p.ptype_id

    ) AS SRC
 PIVOT 
   (MAX(pho_PhoneNum) FOR [description] IN('+@Columns+')
   ) AS PVT
'
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```